# What is the right way to set up and running with code blocks and wxwidgets c++ library

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I struggled for 4 hours to set it up and after installation I am not able to get wxWidgets application started. 
I get an error wx/setup.h no such file or directory found.

I have tried 10 articles from google an none of them seem to resolve the problem.
Has anyone setup the WxWidgets library with CodeBlocks successfully?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what the problem is when you don't say when exactly do you get the error. My *guess* would be that you're trying to build your application without having built wxWidgets first. In this case, it's not going to work as you must build wxWidgets, which will create `setup.h` file in the correct location as a side effect, first. If I'm wrong and you get the error while building wxWidgets itself, please show how do you do it, exactly. In any case, make absolutely sure to **not** copy any `setup.h` files around to get rid of the error, this won't help and can result in other, much more mysterious, problems in the future.

And, to answer your rhetoric question, yes, many people have set up wxWidgets with CodeBlocks successfully. You just need to follow the build instructions instead of random articles found by the web search.